# elements not on the same height in a

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a navbar containing two divs for 'nav-left' and 'nav-right'.
I want to float them left and right plus have the sticky position.

The elements in the navbar are not of the same height. The left elements are up and the right elements are down. I need them to be vertically centered.

```css
 nav {
  position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;

}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-left li {
  float: left;
}

.nav-right li {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="nav-left">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-right">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Bloh</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bloh</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using floats here, you better add `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;` to distribute these two `ul`s left and right. You also need to add `nav ul li { display: inline-block; }` to display these lists horizontally in this case.

(Use top and bottom `padding` on the navbar if you want it to be higher)

```css
nav {
  position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <nav class="nav">
    <div class="nav-left">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-right">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Bloh</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bloh</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problems is that `<ul>` and `<div>` elements are [Block-level Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp).

A better approach is to use flexblox.

Similar to the other answers but without the `<ul>` and `<li>` elements (would be a flexbox in a flexbox). I am using also using `display: flex;` with `justify-content: space-between;`.

I have added `align-self: flex-end;` to right-align items and use a margin to keep the distance between nav items.

Stripped of all irrelevant parts for clarity.

My favorite site to check flexbox from time to time:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;
}

.nav-right {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
<nav class="nav">
  <div>
    <a href="#">Blah</a>
    <a href="#">Blah</a>
    <a href="#">Blah</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-right">
    <a href="#">Bloh</a>
    <a href="#">Bloh</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: sticky;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3rem;
    background: green;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

  }
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  nav a {
    width: 60px;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <nav class="nav">
          <div class="nav-left">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="nav-right">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Bloh</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bloh</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
</body>
</html>
```